# How to use Delete query in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm using `Hibernate` to delete the records from a table,but this giving an exception, could anyone know how to overcome this problem in the below query?

```
 Session ses = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        Transaction tx = ses.beginTransaction();
        Query q = ses.createQuery("from RegisterPojo  where email =:email");
        q.setParameter("email", sl_no);
        RegisterPojo pojo = (RegisterPojo) q.list().get(0);
        ses.delete(pojo);
        tx.commit();
        ses.close();
```

Comment: what exception your getting?

Comment: What is the Exception? share stacktrace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not ?

```
Query q = ses.createQuery("delete from RegisterPojo  where email =:email");
q.setParameter("email", sl_no);
q.executeUpdate();
```

Learn [HQL](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html)

Before proceeding please learn more about hql. That reduces large amount of code.

Comment: am very new to hibernate,is that write way? to use

Comment: @user2838630 pay attention that this solution will delete all the instances `where email =:email`, in your code you were deleting just the first one ...